# CREATE table LIKE a JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
JOIN t2
ON t1.id1 = t2.id2
```

yields a JOIN of those tables on MySQL. How can I store the result in a third table without having to define it column by column.

I tried this to create the third table but it doesn't work.

```
CREATE TABLE t3 LIKE
(
SELECT *
FROM t1
JOIN t2
ON t1.id1 = t2.id2
) a
```

Comment: Do you want the new table to hold the results of the `SELECT`, or just for its schema to be based on that result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the new table to contain the results of your `SELECT`:

```
CREATE TABLE t3 SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.id1 = t2.id2
```

Or if you just want it to be based on the schema of the join:

```
CREATE TABLE t3 SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.id1 = t2.id2 WHERE FALSE
```

Comment: It is important to note that mysql will throw an error if the two tables contain a duplicate column name.

Comment: @MattGlover:  Good point.  Obviously one will have to alias such columns in that event.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
SELECT * into t3
FROM t1
JOIN t2
ON t1.id1 = t2.id2
```

Comment: The question rather suggests that `t3` has not yet been defined.

Comment: I guess I jumped the gun and missed "mysql" part; SQL Server does create a new table with the above...

Comment: Oooh, interesting.  That I didn't know!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) which acts just like a table:

```
CREATE VIEW t3 AS
SELECT *
FROM t1
JOIN t2
ON t1.id1 = t2.id2
```

Then you can reference this view in other joins as if it were its own table.

Comment: The question rather suggests the OP wants a snapshot of the data, not a live copy.